# How to retrieve test results in Vitest afterAll?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vitest

I would like to run a teardown function in `afterAll` in Vitest only if all tests passed. Is there a way to retrieve the test results?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer (thanks Typescript!). The data can be found in tasks:

```
afterAll(async ({ tasks }) => {
  const allPassedOrSkipped = tasks.every((task) => {
    const state = task.result?.state;
    return state == "pass" || state == "skip";
  });
});
```